# Image Onload - Quickbase

Tags: javascript, intuit-partner-platform, quickbase

I'm trying to follow Dan Diebolt's 'Image Onload" technique to inject custom js script however I think I'm tripping up at the first part - the process says:

> Create a field with the following formula definition and include it in
>   your  form/report.

So I've created a text-formula field named '-', allowed HTML and pasted the formula in the "formula" section of the field:

```
[-]=
"<img qbu=\"module\" src=\"/i/clear2x2.gif\" " &
"onload=\"javascript:if(typeof QBU=='undefined'){QBU={};$.getScript('" &
URLRoot() &
"db/" &
Dbid() &
"?a=dbpage&pagename=module.js&rand='+Math.random())}\">"
```

When I attempt to save I get an alert that says "A formula may not contain a reference to itself directly or indirectly through another formula." What am I doing wrong? I've tried adding the field to the form anyway and that doesn't seem to do anything.

These are the steps I'm following:

[https://haversineconsulting.quickbase.com/db/bgcwm2m4g?a=dr&rid=93][1]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[-] =` line.  That's where you're getting the error from. You should just have the following in your formula:

```
"<img qbu=\"module\" src=\"/i/clear2x2.gif\" " &
"onload=\"javascript:if(typeof QBU=='undefined'){QBU={};$.getScript('" &
URLRoot() &
"db/" &
Dbid() &
"?a=dbpage&pagename=module.js&rand='+Math.random())}\">"
```

Comment: Nathan, that is exactly what my problem was. Thank you very (VERY) much.